# Inotify Delete Events are missing

Tags: c++, linux, file, monitoring, inotify

Events are missing when file deleting in the same directory.

inotify monitoring directory : ./test
delete command : rm -rf ./test/*

file count : 20;

but event notify 12, what does this happen?

```
int fileDescripter = inotify_init();
char buffer[BUF_LEN];
int watchDescripter = inotify_add_watch(fileDescripter, path.c_str(), IN_MODIFY | IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE);

while(true)
{
    read(fileDescripter, buffer, BUF_LEN);

    struct inotify_event *evt_inotify = (struct inotify_event*) &buffer;

string filename(evt_inotify->name);
cout << " CATCH : " << path+"/"+filename << endl;

    if(evt_inotify->len){

        if(evt_inotify->mask & IN_CREATE)
        {
            if(evt_inotify->mask & IN_ISDIR)
            {
                cout << "DIR CREATE" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "FILE CREATE" << endl;
            }
        }
        else if(evt_inotify->mask & IN_DELETE)
        {
            if(evt_inotify->mask & IN_ISDIR)
            {
               cout << "DIR DELETE" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
               cout << "FILE DELETE" << endl;
            }

        }
        else if(evt_inotify->mask & IN_MODIFY)
        {
            if(evt_inotify->mask & IN_ISDIR)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }

}\
```

on the 12 line, print is event notify count(12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

inotify_init is blocking mode, inotify_init1(IN_NONBLOCK) use.

inotify_init It takes a lock while reading

helpful posts
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html